# axios stopped working in android suddenly. Live Application

Tags: android, react-native, axios

Axios gives network error in android. Works in IOS.

Usage

```
axios.post('.../manualauth/login', {
    email: this.state.email,
    password: this.state.password,
    remember: ""
  })
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);

      this.validate_response(response);

    }.bind(this))
    .catch(function (error) {
      alert('connection error');
      console.log(error);
      console.log(error.response.data);
      if (error.response) {
      console.log(error.response.data);
      // console.log(error.response.status);
      // console.log(error.response.headers);
    }
    });
```

Error:

```
Error: Network Error
at createError (createError.js:16)
at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:87)
at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (event-target.js:172)
at XMLHttpRequest.setReadyState (XMLHttpRequest.js:546)
at XMLHttpRequest.__didCompleteResponse (XMLHttpRequest.js:381)
at XMLHttpRequest.js:485
at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (EventEmitter.js:181)
at MessageQueue.__callFunction (MessageQueue.js:250)
at MessageQueue.js:101
```

Axios stopped working all of a sudden in android but works in IOS.

Is this something regarding HTTPS issue?

Comment: That output doesn't appear connected to the code you gave... either `console.log(error.response.data);` would complain because `.response` is undefined, or it and the subsequent `if`-protected statement would show the  same information twice (`error.response.data`).

Comment: there is no response from the error data. Thats the real problem.

Comment: It works fine when connected to a HTTP server

Comment: Did it _used_ to work connected to HTTPS? If so, you need to see what may have changed, and/or see if you can get more specific detail than just "_Network Error_".

Comment: Its a live application and its was working until yesterday.
I'll see if i can pull up something adb logcat

Comment: I just encountered the exact issue. All of a sudden, my live app stopped working.

Comment: Were you able to find out  the issue?. And are you using HTTPS for your API's?